# SQL full join on if ... else

Tags: sql, if-statement

A part of my query looks like this:

```
...
FULL JOIN [tbl_ad] as ad
ON [name] = ad.[firstName] + '', '' + ad.[lastName]
...
```

[name] always looks like this (fictive names):

```
Brian, Vines
Michael, Bartels
Timothy, Gilcrease
```

The combination ad.[firstName] + '', '' + ad.[lastName] will return the same:

```
Brian, Vines
Michael, Bartels
Timothy, Gilcrease
```

So now I have a list of 300 users with one user that cause a problem because it's not returning the same value because he have not the same name in both tables.

As [name] she has

```
"Chloe, Jones"
```

but the combination of ad.[firstName] + '', '' + ad.[lastName] is

```
"Chloë, Jones"
```

You see: e <> ë

That's why I would like to use an if in my query, just for this exception... Any idea?

I thought something like this:

```
...
FULL JOIN [tbl_ad] as ad
ON [name] = if [name] == 'Chloe, Jones' 
                'Chloë, Jones'
            else
                ad.[firstName] + '', '' + ad.[lastName]
...
```

Or is this just not possible?

Comment: Changing your database collation might eliminate the need for making this an exception. What happens when Zoë signs up?

Comment: @Widor Indeed, changing it in the DB would be the solution. But I'm not the owner of the DB and I don't know if it's allowed to change it...

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? You can use the [COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) clause within the `JOIN` to dictate which collation to use.

Comment: @Widor Microsoft SQL Server 2008 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the collation of both compared expressions to be **accent insensitive**, so that not only Chloe/Chloë, but any other similar case works for you.

To do so, you simply need to add the `COLLATE` specification after the selected column name. [See COLLATE docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms184391.aspx). For example:

```
ON [name] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI
   = ad.[firstName] + ''  , '' + ad.[lastName] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI
```

NOTE: this sample is Case insensitive, Accent insensitive

If you want to use the "IF" way, you simply need to add an `OR` expression that checks that both composed fields look the way you like:

```
ON [name] = ad.[firstName] + '', '' + ad.[lastName]
  OR ([name] = 'Chloe, Jones' 
      AND ad.[firstName] + '', '' + ad.[lastName] = 'Chloë, Jones')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try CASE (which is supported by many RDBMS)

```
ON CASE WHEN [name] = 'Chloe, Jones' THEN 'Chloë, Jones' ELSE [name] END 
   = ad.[firstName] + ', ' + ad.[lastName]
```